# NHibernate: get all data from all DB tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate

How can I iterate throw mapped entities and get all data from database? I dont know on first place what is mapped by NHibernate...

```
Configuration configuration = SessionProvider.Configuration;
var mappedClasses = configuration.ClassMappings;

IRepository repository = new Repository();

foreach (var mappedClass in mappedClasses)
{
    var enumerable = repository.GetAll<mappedClass>();//<-- this dont work
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you query on `Object`, it queries all mapped classes in the session, so the following returns a list of all records in your database:

```
var completeList = session.CreateCriteria<Object>().List();
```